Arguments received by TimeDistributed.call():
im trying to doing a video classification dl project.
preprocessing: from each video, i took 20 frames and reshaped them and added them to a list , my x.shape looks    like this --> (None, 20, 224, 224, 3)
model: i used vgg16 as base model and a lstm layer in combination.
baseModel = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(frame_height, frame_width, 3))
#model
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(baseModel, input_shape=(sequence, frame_height, frame_width, 3)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.3)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.3)))
#LSTM Layer
model.add(LSTM(320, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(label_count, activation="softmax")) 

for layer in baseModel.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

optimizers = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, validation_data=(x_val,y_val),epochs=1, batch_size=10, callbacks=[early_stopping])

after this i saved the model in my local: model.save("model.keras")
but, when i tried to load the model with :loaded_model = load_model(r'model.keras')
i got a ValueError:
Cannot convert '20' to a shape.
Arguments received by TimeDistributed.call():
• args=('<KerasTensor shape=(None, 20, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=input_layer_3>',)
• kwargs={'mask': 'None'}
i want to save the model for later use and load it when need . im quite new , so anything will help even if there is any better way to preprocess or better model architure .

Hi user26379577 ,you are facing an issue while loading the model.For that, make sure that the input shape is correctly defined and consistent when saving and loading the model, and you can also put the input shape when creating the model, and also check that you are using the same version of TensorFlow/Keras when saving and loading the model. Try to print the shapes of your input data so that you can check it is correct.
